# New permissions showing up on MacOS Catalina with Java application

Tags: java, macos, javafx

Hello other developers.

Today I came here with a doubt and to verify if I can find a solution.

I work for a company that created a java application for MAC. The problem arose with the new Catalina.

Now when the application is installed two new permissions appear on the security. "Full Disk Access" and "Input Monitoring"
The application requires keyboard input and downloads a file to a temporary folder, then moves it to the USB.

For mouse input what we use on our application is [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html)

We also use `java/awt/DefaultKeyboardFocus` and `NodeBuilder`

```
JavaFX - version 8
```

I wanted to check if there is any possibility do make these permissions not to show up, as the client doesn't want them to appear.

Or should we use other APIs for these kinds of accesses?

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: it's [a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8231513) which might happen [not only for fx](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2019-October/023712.html)